# How to run a TVF X number of times to satisfy every condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, function

I have a table valued function that returns a result set something like

```
id     condition state     costs
1      yes                 300
2      yes                 1000
3      yes                 120
4      no                  20
5      no                  240
```

The function itself is based on this query

```
;with x
as
(
select   c.pat_id
        ,sum(std_cost) as Costs
        from claims as c 
        where c.pat_id in
        (
            select   c.pat_id
                from claims as c
                where c.admission_date between '2007-01-01' and '2007-01-31'
        )
        group by c.pat_id

),y
as
(
    select c.pat_id
        from claims as c
        inner join icd_patient as i
        on i.id=c.id
        inner join tblicd as t
        on t.icd=i.icd
        where t.icd like '707%'
        group by c.pat_id
)               

select   [Condition State]
        ,count(*) as  [Number Patients]
        ,avg(costs) as [Average Healthcare costs]
    from
    (
    select   x.pat_id
            ,case when y.pat_id is null then 'Condition Absent' else 'Condition Present' end as [Condition State]
            ,costs
            from x
            left join y on x.pat_id=y.pat_id
    )r
    group by [Condition State]
```

The line `LIKE '707%'` is of course replaced by a parameter in the function.  I have a table called `tbliICD` that has a list of codes which is the source of the input parameter in this function.  I would like to know how I could go about running this query for every code in the table `tblicd`.  What kind of method could I use to do this?  Is it possible to send in a table value parameter containing every code I need and have it run the function once for every code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CROSS APPLY. It will look something like this:

```
SELECT
  t.col, t.code, f.id, f.conditionState, f.costs
FROM yourTable AS t
CROSS APPLY dbo.yourTVF(t.code) AS f;
```

If your function is an inline TVF, this can be quite efficient.

Comment: cross apply is exactly what I was looking for :)